# Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services heapster)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and is trying to deploy one master and 2 nodes. I completed the installation in master and the pods are running.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-node-g2fxl                1/1     Running   0          5m56s
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-2jpfq         1/1     Running   0          7m59s
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-bxvct         1/1     Running   0          7m59s
kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1     Running   0          7m19s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1     Running   0          7m16s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1     Running   0          7m7s
kube-system   kube-proxy-jg2cp                 1/1     Running   0          7m59s 
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1     Running   0          7m8s
```

I can curl localhost:8001 successfully, but unable to access kube dashboard from my laptop using private IP of this server (I am connected to VPN and SSH to this master VM using this private IP). checking the logs shows me:

```
Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

Googling and found these (https://brookbach.com/2018/10/29/Heapster-on-Kubernetes-1.11.3.html and https://elatov.github.io/2018/06/installing-heapster-for-kubernetes/). But still unsuccessful in getting the dashboard from outside. Can someone please guide me correctly.

Comment: If I remember, heapter is deprecated, you need to use metric server service

Comment: @c4f4t0r: It was said here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944258) to install heapster. Any idea?

Comment: I prefer to no use the dashboard, in place to use a deprecated component.

Comment: @c4f4t0r: so, do you mean to say there's no other way to get dashboard working?

Comment: looking for in google "tesla kubernetes dashboard"

Comment: Thanks @c4f4t0r, I do understand the criticality of exposing dashboard to internet. But my case is different. I need dashboard access using my private IP of the VM so that I can only connect to it over my corporate VPN. Hope you understand my requirement and scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should expose your Dashboard UI (service/kubernetes-dashboard) on NodePort type Service, instead of ClusterIP, if you want to access it via private IP of cluster node, as explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above).

Confirmed to be working fine in following configuration:

[image]

Kubernetes: v1.13.4
Heapster image: k8s.gcr.io/heapster-amd64:v1.5.3
Dashboard: k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution:

```
 kubectl -n kube-system edit service kubernetes-dashboard
```

change the:

```
  type: ClusterIP
```

to

```
  type: NodePort
```

Next check the ports mapping

```
kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard

NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort   10.103.252.123   <none>        443:30287/TCP   6m51s
```

In this case connect using `https://_MASTER_IP_:30287`

This is works for me ..

Answer (score 0):

When it happened to me, I just added `hostNetwork : True` to yaml file and reapplied it.